# group same faces using opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I am trying to group faces in a folder using the opencv.

I am playing around with eigenfaces example at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_tutorial.html. but cannot find anything to solve my problem.

```
I have a set of faces in my face database: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I
As a result I try to get; 
 - A,B,D are person1
 - C,E,F are person2 
 - G,H   are person3
 - I     is person4
```

I gues the process should be like;

```
sampleFace = A
while  
  mode.train(faces,labels) // trains face database 
  model.predict(sampleFace, &predict, &confidence) // get the prediction 
  using the confidence and similarity percentage decide A,B,D faces are person1
  remove A,B,D from face database and remove the labels of these images also 
  if faces.size=1 exit loop
  sampleFace = C
end of loop
```

To get that result, I think I need to set a thresholg to my model in the eigen faces sample. And need to use the confidence value.

Actually I want to set a similarity score like %80, then I want to get images which has similarity score bigger than %80 with the given sample face. The eigenfaces sample gives only one similar face with a confidence value. I need to get multiple faces with confidence value per each one, then I can compare the similarity scores. Also in the eigenfaces sample I do not know the limits of confidence, I need a percentage value per each face.

Any help,advice, or code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you are trying to do is based on unsupervised learning, which will not work well on face images. If you have enough number of samples per person, you'd better train a classifier with at least one image of a person; then find the nearest class for each image in your dataset.